# Webpack Dev Server Reloading Not Working

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack Dev Server. When I update my files, the browser doesn't refresh, even though it should. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The fiendish cause behind this is having `webpack-dev-server` globally installed, but not locally. Typing `webpack-dev-server` will still *appear* to work, but actually not work at all, causing this consternation.

The following code fixes the problem:
`npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 0):

If you run it trought the command line with a npm script command.

Try to add
`-watch or -w` options to make webpack watch your project file and re-build when a change is made.

Comment: Thank you but I think that answer relates only to `webpack` implementaitons that do not use `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: Good ! Just in case ;)